# Portal type application with AngularJS (Multiple Independent apps)

Tags: ajax, angularjs, portal

We are trying to create a portal type application with multiple / independent "sub-apps". Assuming that all sub-apps are written in Angular what is a good pattern to achieve the following goals.

1. Each app can be developed and deployed independent of each other.
2. They share a common authentication service, they can share common libraries (directives, filters etc).
3. Only one app will be visible and active at any given time. The scope of each sub-app is isolated from each other.
4. When the users goes between the sub-apps, the state is maintained as long as the user does not refresh the page or visit another static link. (I think this is built into Angular and no special effort maybe needed)
5. Each sub-app will have more than one views (it will have its own menu). There will be a top menu based on what sub-apps are available. Ideally the top menu is dynamically build based on what sub-apps are deployed. Maybe there is a server side component to this (the server detects the folder structure etc and determines what apps are deployed and injects the necessary js code into the page).

Given the fact that AngularJs does not have multi-level view structure, I was thinking of using multiple ng-app declarations on different divs and then using $window scope to store the key of the active app and hide the ones which are not active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy answer to your (rather open) question, but regarding the $route and ngView limitations, I have been having great success employing a technique derived from this: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2420-Mapping-AngularJS-Routes-Onto-URL-Parameters-And-Client-Side-Events.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I also have been thinking of trying to implement. While I don't have a complete working solution, I believe that this type of portal app would consist of multiple angular apps on the same page.

The portal app would be the traditional ng-app directive on the main page and the "portlets" would be dynamically created and manually bootstrapped angular apps on a sub view div. You can share data, state, authentication, personalization, etc from injecting the portal services (contained in their own module) that provide these features into the manually bootstrapped portlet apps.

The tricky part is how the portal app would discover the portlet apps and serve up their angular modules knowing that these apps would be independently deployed web apps with their own urls.

I still have some questions around if the service data would be common between the apps or if you would need to try and leverage HTML5 local storage via the portal service (like a data manager).