# AngularJS authenticate once to use multiple apps

Tags: angularjs

## What I'm trying to do

I'm about to build a portal-style application much like what was described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774903/portal-type-application-with-angularjs-multiple-independent-apps).
The behaviour I'm looking for I hope is best described by the sequence of mockups below:
[image: Login at mainsite.com/]
[image: Once logged in, user has access to 3 separate Angular apps]
[image: From within any given app, the user's creds are accessible]

To summarise the behaviour I'm after:

1. A user goes to mainsite.com/ and is asked to sign in and once authenticated three links to three different apps are displayed.
2. Clicking on any given app (mainsite.com/app1/ in the example above) would take one to each app but remembering that the user is logged in. This would work if one could nest ngApps but I don't know that one can.

## Potential approaches (that I can think)

1. Attach authentication logic and data to the $window (kind of like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301554/is-it-possible-to-share-data-between-two-angularjs-apps)). A page refresh would kill this presumably, and it would involve having 4 apps in the page (the three sub-apps and one to play the role of the main page app.
2. Drop a cookie with the relevant session info that gets picked up whenever one travels to any to sub-apps and between them. I feel uneasy about this, but shows some promise?
3. I don't have third idea at this juncture.

I guess what I'm looking for is an extension of the awesome [http-auth-interceptor](http://ngmodules.org/modules/http-auth-interceptor) module but with persistence across apps.

Has anyone come across this problem and solved it or have any other ideas on how to solve it? The solution might even be lurching in something like the design I've got in mind for making the portal work but I can't see it.

Any ideas welcome and very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the wrong answer, but that stick to how this problem is currently solved  : often, developers relies on server-side authentication, considering auth a different application and a different problem than full-client side programming.

Now if you want to do it only on the client side, it is still feasible, but you have to keep in mind that templates will always be accessible by a non-authenticated user. Here is [an article](http://frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/) about the subject and it's associated [github repository](https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth). It does not rear multiple apps, but by tweaking [this service](https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth/blob/master/client/js/services.js) you could achieve the trick. This solution use cookies as you mentionned.

Here is a [very relevant blog article](http://blog.auth0.com/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/) that complete the answer to your question : what are the potential approaches. In short : use token.

Comment: Thanks @davidb583. That's essentially what I ended up doing. Token stored as cookie on client-side, accessed using AngularJS's cookieStore service and shoving the token in subsequent calls to the API. The last article is a great one. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

As to your approaches:

1. Not a good idea. You already explained why.
2. This works, although you
   cannot store much in a cookie(session ID and login name at most)

In my current project I store user data (session token, name, id, roles etc) in the HTML5 [session storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). The web storage is accessible from all of your apps running in your HTML5 compliant browser.

I use Witold Szczerba's HTTP Auth Interceptor Module for AngularJS ([http-auth-interceptor](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth)) and [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) for backend communication. On application start I check, whether there is authentication data available. If so, the authentication token is passed to subsequent REST calls.

```
/* Read authentication data from web storage */
var authData = this.getAuthData();
if (isDefined(authData)) {

      /* Make sure all subsequent REST calls are sent with auth token */
      Restangular.setDefaultHeaders(({auth:authData.token}));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lars Behnke. I ended up doing pretty much what you describe, although I went with cookies instead of session storage or any of the HTML5 storage options as there was uncertainty around clients' browser capabilities. I had a token that was attached to all requests after the original authentication. I also used Angular UI router to have "sub-apps" appear under one main login page. That made it so much easier. I feel like this is not an uncommon problem, but hard to see working code. I might put something up to help others that come here with a similar problem. Thanks.